# Linux Command: Directory inside a directory

Tags: linux, command-line, directory

So I have have a directory - lets say /dir/.
In it I have these folders-
/dir/fold1/
/dir/fold2/
/dir/fold3/

each of these folders (fold1,2,3) may contain a folder called foo. I want to list all the folders inside dir, that have inside them a folder called foo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
ls -R /dir | grep -i foo
```

Breaking down the command we have:
`ls -R` =  Lists files recursively (including directories

`grep -i foo` = Will take the command above and filter it case-insensitive to display any instances of 'foo'.

Comment: How do I make this command not print every directory which I don't have access permissions to?

Comment: You should be able to redirect stderr.  Something like this: ls -R /dir 2>/dev/null | grep -i foo

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
find dir -type d -name foo
```

So... `dir` is the directory you want to search.

`-type` is they type of what you're looking for: **d**irectory, **f**ile or **l**ink.

`-name` is the name of what you're looking for, case sensitive.  You can use `-iname` if you want it to be case insensitive.

Comment: This lists all the foo folders, not the contents of their parents.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -ld /dir/*/foo | grep ^d
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose:

```
find /dir -name foo -type d -exec dirname {} \; | xargs ls
```

but this does not work if any directory has whitespaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all of the directories which only contain a subdirectory named `foo` at the first level, you can do

```
for x in /dir/*; do
  [ -d $x/foo ] && ls $x
done
```

The `[ ... ]` construct is an abbreviation for the shell built-in `test`.  `-d $x/foo` tests if the `$x/foo` exists and is a directory.  If it does, then `ls $x` is executed.